# Vagrant on Windows 8 loads wrong index.php

Tags: php, windows, vagrant, home-directory

I'm new to Vagrant and Virtual Box, but I've got this Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian-7.2.0"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/197673519/debian-7.2.0.box"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip:"172.17.2.3"

  config.vm.synced_folder("./data", "/vagrant", nfs: (RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/ or RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/))

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 1024
    v.cpus = 2
  end

  $script = <<EOF
mkdir -p /etc/puppet/modules
(puppet module list | grep puppetlabs-apt) ||
   puppet module install puppetlabs-apt --version 1.4.2
EOF

  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => $script

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "base.pp"
    puppet.options = ['--verbose --debug']
  end

end
```

In my `hosts` file I have:

```
172.17.2.3      local.dev
```

The problem is, when I go in browser to local.dev I see: "It works!" message, but not the index.php which is located in `data/www/` (`data` is in the same level as Vagrantfile)

How can I start working so I can load files from `data/www`? Or is there any better approach?

Comment: You'd need to reconfigure the installed web-server to use `data/www` as its document root. Which web-server do you use? Apache or nginx?

Comment: I believe it's Apache. I'm really sorry if it sounds stupid, but I'm not into servers - how do I check? VirtualBox shows it's Linux Debian (64bit)

Comment: Run `vagrant ssh` and you should end up with a shell to the VM. Then run `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and change the document root. Hit CTRL+X and then press Y and then Enter to save. Now restart apache2 with `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: That worked :) If You posted this as an answer, I would accept it. By the way - can vagrant be launched already with needed document root?

Comment: I'll do that. Instead of destroying the VM, you can shut it down it with `vagrant halt` and the next time you run `vagrant up`, the old VM will be used instead of setting up a new one. However, `vagrant destroy` will remove the configuration you just did.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But if I want another app in the future, then I have to repeat this config edit again and there's no way in some vagrant config to define Apache document root, right?

Comment: Not that I know of, you could try asking the Vagrant community and see if they have some inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the Apache2 web-server needs to be reconfigured and change the DocumentRoot.

Run `vagrant ssh` and you will end up with a shell to the Virtual Machine. Change the DocumentRoot with `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> hit <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, run `sudo service apache2 restart` to restart apache2 with the new configuration.